# How do I calculate aggregates on a dataset which needs grouping?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset where measurements were taken at sensors (1-16), variable number of times, which then repeats. I would like the mean of the `value` for each sensor in each sequence. Not all sequences go back to 1 from 16 (sometimes there are stray measurements that need to be removed). Note: This is a small, fake dataset.

The [dataset](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karthik/ad2874e5b5c5f3af73ad89d14b26a913/raw/f435317539bc56a09b248a0ef193db21b7176eee/small.csv) (can also be read with the script below)

```
# To read with rio  
# library("devtools")
# install_github("leeper/rio")
library("rio")
df <- import("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karthik/ad2874e5b5c5f3af73ad89d14b26a913/raw/f435317539bc56a09b248a0ef193db21b7176eee/small.csv")
```

My first attempt:

```
library(dplyr)
# Assigning groups to the data
df$diff <- c(df$sensor[2:nrow(df)], 0) - df$sensor
# There is sometimes a sensor reading between 16 and 1. This removes those rows.
df2 <- df[-which(df$diff < 0 & df$sensor != 16),]

# end is now where the last 16 was
end <- which(df2$diff < 0)
# Start begins with 1, then adds 1 to the position of every last 16 sensor
# reading to get the next 1
start <-
  c(1, which(df2$diff < 0)[1:length(which(df2$diff < 0)) - 1] + 1)
# Now combine both into a data.frame
positions <- data_frame(start, end)
# Add unique groups
positions$group <- 1:nrow(positions)
df2$group <- NA

# Yes this is a horrible loop and 
# super inefficient on the full dataset.
for (i in 1:nrow(positions)) {
  df2[positions[i,]$start:positions[i, ]$end, ]$group <-
    positions[i,]$group
}
```

Now it becomes easy to do the aggregation with `dplyr`

```
df3 <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(sensor,group) %>% 
  summarise(mean_value = mean(value))
  head(df3)
```

Resulting in what I want.

```
  Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
  Groups: sensor [4]

  sensor group mean_value
  (int) (int)      (dbl)
  1      1     2 0.07285933
  2      2     2 0.06993007
  3      3     1 0.04845651
  4      3     2 0.03976837
  5      4     1 0.06033732
  6      4     2 0.06480888
```

What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating the `positions` dataframe, creating the intermediate dataframe `df2` and adding a grouping variable with a for-loop, you can do everything with the `dplyr` vocabulary. By using a combination of `cumsum` and `lag` you add a grouping variable with `mutate`. This results in a much more simplified procedure:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(differ = lead(sensor) - sensor) %>% 
  filter(!(differ < 0 & sensor != 16)) %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(lag(differ,default=0) < 0) + 1) %>% 
  group_by(sensor, grp) %>% 
  summarise(mean_val = mean(value))
```

which gives:

```
Source: local data frame [30 x 3]
Groups: sensor [?]

   sensor   grp   mean_val
    (int) (dbl)      (dbl)
1       1     2 0.07285933
2       2     2 0.06993007
3       3     1 0.04845651
4       3     2 0.03976837
5       4     1 0.06033732
6       4     2 0.06480888
7       5     1 0.03276722
8       5     2 0.05005240
9       6     1 0.06967405
10      6     2 0.06484712
..    ...   ...        ...
```

NOTE: I used `differ` as a variable name instead of `diff` because the latter is also a function (and it is not wise to give your columns a 'funcion'-name).

---

You could also use the `data.table` package for this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, differ := shift(sensor, type='lead') - sensor
          ][!(differ < 0 & sensor != 16)
            ][, grp := cumsum(shift(differ,fill=0) < 0) + 1
              ][, .(mean_val = mean(value)), .(sensor,grp)]
```

in which `setDT(df)` will convert your dataframe into a datatable.